# Java: Intellij package prefix and resource files

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I'm confused about how Intellij handles resources in a java project. I need my resources at the package level, i.e. next to the class files so I can use getClass.getResource(). I have been able to put them there by marking my resources folder as a "source root" and then adding the package prefix under Module Settings. This works, however the problem is that some of my resources are in subdirectories under the resources folder, and as soon as I add a subdirectory, Intellij assumes that that's a different package. On the other hand if I mark the folder as a "resource root" I do not have the option to use the package prefix feature. Does this mean I can't do these things together and have to give up using package prefix and set up the package hierachy manually?

Comment: My issue is that I can't seem to use the package prefix feature together with a resource folder!

Comment: Sorry I don't think you understand my question. I'm using the package prefix feature in Intellij idea, under Module Settings and I'm trying to make that work with a resource folder including nested folders. The code for getting the resource is not relevant. Intellij does not allow me to do these two things together as far as I can tell.

Comment: Okay, fair enough, I didnt really understand the question then.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "assumes it's a different package"?

Comment: @yole, if mark the resource folder as "Sources Root" and add the package prefix, for example "com.company.appname", and then add a subfolder called "icons", IntelliJ assumes that the icons belong to a subpackage called "com.company.appname.icons", which of course doesn't exist so it gives an error.

Comment: Do I understand correctly that you want to put your resources into multiple directories and have them all be visible as if they were in the same package? IntelliJ IDEA does not support such a setup.

Comment: Not exactly, what I would like to do is to use the package prefix for resources just the same as for source files. Using the package prefix means I don't have to create the folder hierarchy for my package which means there's not so much clutter. Apparently this feature doesn't work with resource files, I'm kind of suprised because putting resources at package level is a pretty basic concept, given that getClass().getResource() automatically adds the package folder hierarchy to relative paths.